# Using find command but getting the error "paths must precede expression"

Tags: unix

I'm trying to use the find command, but get "paths must exceed expression:name"

I've looked at the answers given here previously and added quotes around my expression, but it still is giving me the same error. My $SUB path is /home/year/sessions/subjects/MRI

```
    find $SUB \( -name '*first*.tgz' -o name '*second*.tgz' \) -exec cp {} ./$SUBJECT1 \;
```

Is my path-to-file incorrect? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to [so], we're an Developing community, I think your question will fit better at [su].

Comment: Missing - before the second name and don't name your var with capital letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct command is:

```
  find $SUB \( -name '*first*.tgz' -o -name '*second*.tgz' \) -exec cp {} ./$SUBJECT1 \;
```